# How to populate _id field with string filed in mongodb node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two collections user and comments.In user there is fields :

```
const user = mongoose.Schema({
    _id                 :("In the form of ObjectID"), 
                      //ObjectId("5a19086e0664e832842f2c24")
    user_name                   :{type: String},
    password                    : {type: String}
});
```

and comments collection:

```
const comments = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id                     :{type: String},
                //"5a19086e0664e832842f2c24" this is user's _id
    comment                    : {type: String}
});
```

Now I want to know that how to populate this 2 collection with the user's _id which is in string type in comment collection.
Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to update your schema as it requires the reference of the collection you want to populate:

```
const user = mongoose.Schema({
    user_name: { type: String },
    password: { type: String }
});

const comments = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    comment: { type: String }
});
```

***Note:*** I removed the _id field as it will be added automatically. Also take note that `_id` is an `ObjectId` not just a string (even though you can consider it as a string).

Then you can use the `populate()` method:

```
Comments.find({}).populate('user_id').exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you already can use String to populate an ObjectId like this :

```
const user = mongoose.Schema({
    user_name                   : {type: String},
    password                    : {type: String}
}); // users._id will natively be an ObjectId 

const comments = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id                    : {type: String, ref:'users'}, // user_id has to be referenced with your "users" model
    comment                    : {type: String}
});

Comment.find({}).populate('user_id').exec();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes that's true, however the mongoose documentation recommends to always use an ObjectId unless there is a reason not to do so. `Note: ObjectId, Number, String, and Buffer are valid for use as refs. However, you should use ObjectId unless you are an advanced user and have a good reason for doing so`, see: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html